# search all files in a directory and get their full path using bash script

Tags: bash

I have a directory structure like this.ABC/123, ABC/456, ABC/789 and in each of the numbered directories i have many files.what i want is to be able to search all files named XYZ.txt found in the numbered directories from the ABC directory and get their full paths on a variable or on an array using a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
cd "ABC"
array=($(find "$PWD" -type f -name "XYZ.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave away the cd ABC, otherwise "ABC/" will not be part of the output. find searches the curent directory, which makes specifying $PWD dispensable. Also the constraint to files by -type is not necessary if you define the name with .txt extension, supposed there aren't any directories called like this.

```
array=($(find -name "*.txt"))
```